# Will using Ngram Tokenizer and Ngram Filters increase the index size in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am new to Elasticsearch, does NGram Tokenizer and NGram Filter increase the index size in Elasticseach?

Using

```
MIN_NGRAM AS 1
MAX_NGRAM AS 50
```

And how to check index size and tokens using localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using (edge) ngram tokenizers or filters will increase the index size - you're storing more tokens, after all.

As a couple of side notes, `min_gram` set to 1 may allow you to perform autocomplete operations on the first keystroke, but unless your dataset is small you're unlikely to provide a narrow enough resultset to the user to be useful. `min_gram` set to 2 or 3 is a better balance for larger datasets and performance. `max_gram` set to 50 has a similar problem but at the other extreme; a user is unlikely to type in that many characters in order to autocomplete anything, so you're indexing ngrams unnecessarily in that case. Of course, these comments are specific to the autocomplete use-case; I'm sure there are many workable scenarios needing 1, 50 for `min_gram` and `max_gram`.

The ES reference documentation has some details on the status API - best to try it and see the output:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-status/

To determine how ES is tokenizing your input:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze/